# Limit on the number of visible <div> in HTML

Tags: html, layer

IS there any limit on the number of visible layers that can be ther in an HTML file ?

I'm creating new  layers but none of them seem to show up,when i view the webpage O_o

Comment: You need to post your code to see what and how you are doing it.

Comment: as the code is very big,ill jsut post the relevant parts 

#closeaa {
font-size:12px;
font-weight:bold;
font-family:Segoe UI;
visibility:visible;
 position:absolute;
 width:176px;
 height:21px;
 z-index:24;
 left: 325px;
 top: 114px;
}

and for the <div> tag ... <div id="closeaa">asddddddddddddddddddddddddd</div>

Comment: maybe you have a css rule that says body div {display: none}

Comment: actually,in Dreamweaver,in design mode i can see the layer,but if i open the page on any browser, the new layer doesn't show up

Comment: i just changed the position of the <div> tag in the HTML file,and it worked :/ . WHy did this happen ?

Comment: @Anant - when @Sarfraz says "post code", as I have seen in two of your questions, he doesn't mean here in the comments area.  He means edit your question.  Doing a nice job presenting code shows respect towards the people you are asking for help. It will also get you better results, faster.

Answer (score 1):

According to the specifications and given the strength of browsers I don't see why there should be a limit.
I think these are CSS rules which hide some elements.

Answer (score 0):

[XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/) doesn't say anything about limits and HTML is even more unrestricted, so probably there is no limit at all.

You've most likely lost one '<' or '>' symbol somewhere, or forgotten to close an attribute. Check it carefully.